# UNION ALL de todas las columnas del mismo nombre de tablas diferentes - Mysql

Tags: sql, mysqli

Utilizo Mysql. Tengo 6 tablas que contienen entre 80 y 100 columnas cada una, y necesito realizar un UNION ALL entre todas ellas, devolviendo solo las columnas con el mismo nombre (sino no se podría realizar el UNION ALL).

Entre las tablas, hay algunas columnas que tienen el mismo nombre y otras que no, por eso a priori necesito detectcar cuáles columnas tengo que utilizar. Como sabemos, para realizar una unión de todos, las columnas seleccionadas de las tablas deben tener el mismo nombre.

El problema es que no sé de antemano cuáles columnas son las que están en todas las tabla. Hasta ahora lo hago "a mano", comprobando una por una si está en todas las tablas, perdiendo mucho tiempo, y quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de automatizarlo.

```
TABLE 1 TIENE LAS COLUMAS A, B, C, D
TABLE 2 TIENE LAS COLUMAS A, B, C, D, E 
TABLE 3 TIENE LAS COLUMAS A, B, C, D 
TABLE 4 TIENE LAS COLUMAS A, B, C, D, E, F
TABLE 5 TIENE LAS COLUMAS A, B, C, D, E
TABLE 6 TIENE LAS COLUMAS A, B, C
```

La unión de todas las tablas debe realizarse utilizando las columnas A, B y C porque estas están en todas las tablas. No sé de antemano que A, B Y C son esas columnas.

Gracias.

Comment: No exactamente, todas las tablas deben tener el mismo número de columnas, el nombre de cada una es irrelevante. De lo que tienes que preocuparte es de que los campos similares aparezcan en el mismo orden en cada tabla

Answer (score 0):

No exactamente, todas las tablas deben tener el mismo número de columnas, el nombre de cada una es irrelevante, el servidor únicamente te devolverá el alias de las primeras. De lo que tienes que preocuparte es de que los campos semánticamente idénticos aparezcan en el mismo orden en cada tabla y, al menos por ahora, no se me ocurre forma de automatizarlo.

En tu caso concreto, como todas las tablas parecen empezar por los mismos campos y su nombre no nos preocupa, sino su contenido, puedes plantear la siguiente consulta, colocando los nombres de campo que procedan, en vez de `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E` y `F`:

```
SELECT A, B, C, D, NULL E, NULL F FROM tabla1
UNION ALL
SELECT A, B, C, D, E, NULL F FROM tabla2
UNION ALL
SELECT A, B, C, D, NULL E, NULL F FROM tabla3
UNION ALL
SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F FROM tabla4
UNION ALL
SELECT A, B, C, D, E, NULL F FROM tabla5
UNION ALL
SELECT A, B, C, NULL D, NULL E, NULL F FROM tabla6;
```